# Where Did the "Pinocchio" trope of Bringing Your Creation To Life Start?

Tags: history-of, trope

This evening I was watching *Coppelia*, a ballet where a toymaker tries to bring a doll he made to life.  *Coppelia* premiered in 1870 and the story of Pinocchio was written in 1870.  This shows up even earlier, in 1823, in *Frankenstein*, where Victor Frankenstein creates a corpse and brings it to live, and recently in *Star Trek* (where, in *Requiem for Methuselah*, Flint creates Rayna and attempts to make her "real" by giving her emotions), and in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, where Data is even called Pinocchio, both on screen and in the series bible.

Where did this trope start?  Is there evidence of stories of making a creation that seems almost like a lifelike human and trying to bring it to life from even before *Frankenstein*?

Comment: The story doesn't quite fit the specifications (mostly due to the lack of intentionally), but I would be remiss if I didn't mention [Búri](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Búri), who was licked into shape by a primordial super-cow (yes, really)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Pygmalion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_%28mythology%29) (so, at the latest, the trope is dated 8AD, in Ovid's [Metamorphoses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphoses_%28poem%29)).

The story itself predates Ovid and comes from Ancient Greeks.

Statue's name was Galatea (not named by Ovid but given in Apollodorus's Bibliotheca, which predates Ovid).

---

If you go into religions, you of course also have Hebrew god giving life to Adam, and assorted Greek gods doing the a similar (but "god-created" instead of "human-created" trope ([Hephaestus and Zeus both](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_%28mythology%29#Parallels_in_Greek_myth))

Comment: Ohhh!  Good one.  I was sure a trope like this would go WAY far back!  And I had forgotten that when I was looking.  So you don't have a reference of anything written on stone tablets that pre-dates this, do you?

Comment: I doubt that Adam counts. He was in no way a doll or statue made alive by a human. Pinocchio and Galatea are both created in a human society, the point is that they become "alive" in a sense resembling (already existing) humans.

Comment: @TangoOversway The [golem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golem) traditions date even further back, but golems created by humans usually have no will. DVK: the Hebrew god wasn't the first to create humans, but that's a different idea from humans creating another sentient being.

Comment: @Gilles - I edited the answer to clarify the distinction.

Comment: Religion has the idea of God creating man, but it isn't far from that to stories of men trying to create life, imitating God. I would be rather surprised if stories like that aren't basically as old as stories can be old.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly dealing with fiction in the context of humans bringing their creations to life, don't forget the Golem.

[Christoph Arlond in 1674](http://books.google.com/books?id=YINYl4iv4ecC&lpg=PA298&ots=euQXjMVxbF&dq=Christoph%20Arnold%20in%201674&pg=PA298#v=onepage&q=Christoph%20Arnold%20in%201674&f=false) and [an unnamed Polish author perhaps in 1630-1640](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Ba%27al_Shem_of_Chelm#The_Golem_of_Che.C5.82m) tell the story of Rabbi Eliyahu of Chelm and the creation of his Golem. A couple centuries later, when Shelley's *Frankenstein* began popularizing the theme, [German authors began retelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golem#Sources_of_the_Prague_narrative) [a variation of this story involving Judah Loew ben Bezalel, the Rabbi of Prague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golem#The_classic_narrative%3a_The_Golem_of_Prague).

(The golem stories tell of a rabbi who seeks to copy what the Hebrew God did with Adam, and fashions a creature of clay that he imbues with life. In the stories, the rabbis bring the clay sculptures to life by inscribing a scroll with the word "truth" upon it and putting the scroll on or in the golem.)